# vs code intellisense problem in case of blazor projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor

I start to use vs code on my mac. But i have a problem with intellisense functionality.
What extensions are You using to program in blazor apps. in general on my side vs dosn't recognize for example own components or when i use mudblazor then i get no property informations in components.
In general the project is building / starting all is fine. But the work is hard.
In Vs for mac all is fine.

I used razor, blazor extensions but this dosn't help